# Flutter: how to export/save a CustomPainter draw to a string coordinates or image base64?

Tags: flutter, canvas, base64, export, paint

I have a CustomPainter where the user must draw multiples lines pointing various things on a image. I need export all these lines to a array of strings or image base64. Is this possible?
My code is like:

```
class Signature extends CustomPainter {
  List<Offset> points;
  Signature({this.points});

  @override
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
    Paint paint = new Paint()
      ..color = Colors.black
      ..strokeCap = StrokeCap.round
      ..strokeWidth = 5.0;

    for (int i = 0; i < points.length - 1; i++) {
      if (points[i] != null && points[i + 1] != null) {
        canvas.drawLine(points[i], points[i + 1], paint);
      }
      canvas.clipRect(Offset.zero & size);
    }
  }

  @override
  bool shouldRepaint(Signature oldDelegate) => oldDelegate.points != points;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a Image and listem to the CustomPaiter you made, then gets the render and convert it to a base64 string

for example:

```
// getter canvas to image
 Future<ui.Image> get rendered {
    var size = context.size;
    ui.PictureRecorder recorder = ui.PictureRecorder();
    Canvas canvas = Canvas(recorder);
    Signature= Signature(points: _points);
    painter.paint(canvas, size);
    return recorder.endRecording().toImage(size.width.floor(), size.height.floor());
  }

// function to convert to String    
Future<String> convertCanvasToB64() async  {
    final img = await rendered;
    final pngBytes = await img.toByteData(format: ui.ImageByteFormat.png);
    final imgBase64 = base64.encode(pngBytes!.buffer.asUint8List());
    return imgBase64;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for this solution!